# Copy S3 file from one folder to another

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am wondering if it is possible in Laravel 5 to copy a stored file from one folder to another within AWS.

Thus with something like:

```
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->copy('/old/s3/location/123.jpg', '/new/s3/location/123.jpg');
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to download the image first and then upload it again?

Comment: Have you tried it? According to the documentation [you can](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem).

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't copy, and there is no error...

Answer (score 3):

With a little workaround I got it to work and like this:

```
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$images = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('oldfolder/image/');
foreach($images as $image) {
    $new_loc = str_replace('oldfolder/image/', 'newfolder/image/', $image);
    $s3->copy($image, $new_loc);
}
```

The crux was in the fact that the $image has the full path already

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move or copy files from one folder to another easily. For moving file you can use below code:-

```
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3')->move('folder1/1587195169.mp4', 'folder1/1587195169.mp4');
```

For copying a file you can use:-

```
$s=Storage::disk('s3')->copy('folder1/1587195169.mp4', 'folder1/1587195169.mp4');
```